# Windows phone 8 viewport control

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, controls, viewport

I try to understand how windows phone viewport control Bounds work.
So i can give

```
viewport.Bunds = new Rect(x,y,width, height);
```

but what that bound stand for is it a scrollable area in the `viewport`.
Can anyone give me a working simple example of it cause whenever i try to use this parameter i can't scroll in `viewport` whatsover

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <ViewportControl Name="tuzik" Bounds="0,0,300,400"  Margin="66,117,20,41" >
        <Canvas Name="canvas">
        <Image Name="TestImage" Source="Assets\testimage.jpg"  
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Canvas.Left="-379" Canvas.Top="-769" Stretch="Fill" />
        </Canvas>
    </ViewportControl>
    <Rectangle   x:Name="rect" Width="300" Height="400" Margin="60,111,63,0" Stroke="Aqua"  />
</Grid>
```

Comment: What is that ViewportControl?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is the Canvas within the ViewportControl.  Canvas does not expand to fill the ViewportControl and will not expand to contain the contents, either.  You have to set a Width and Height on the Canvas.

(At least, that's how I have mine setup.)